# adjusting width of columns in DBGrid

Tags: delphi, dbgrid

I am new to delphi :). I have made a simple app that is able to write and read from SQL server database. I am displaying query results in DBGrid.

Currently, I have only 3 columns in my DB (ID, Name, Surname). DBGrid displays them in a waz that I dont like. I can see ID (its width is accurate) and Name, which is stretched all the way to the right, so I have to use horizontal scrollbar to see Surname, which is also extremely wide.

How can I tell DBGrid to adjust width of columns to the widest row?

My app looks like this:

```
 implementation

 {$R *.dfm}

 procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);

 begin

 ADOQuery1.SQL.Text := 'INSERT INTO [dbo].[client] ([Meno],[Priezvisko]) ' +
                  'VALUES(:Meno, :Priezvisko)';
 ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Meno').Value := Edit1.Text;
 ADOQuery1.Parameters.ParamByName('Priezvisko').Value := Edit2.Text;
 ADOQuery1.ExecSQL;

 end;

 procedure TForm1.Button2Click(Sender: TObject);
 begin

 ADOQuery2.SQL.Text := 'SELECT * FROM [dbo].[client] WHERE Meno = :Meno';
 ADOQuery2.Active := True;
 ADOQuery2.Parameters.ParamByName('Meno').Value := Edit1.Text;
 ADOQuery2.ExecSQL;
 end;

 end.
```

I have found this [TUTORIAL](http://delphi.about.com/od/usedbvcl/a/dbgrid_autofit.htm) but according to this, you have t double click on chosen coumn to adjust its width, and I had also problems with this line

```
 ColumnWidthHelper.MaxWidth := Max(ColumnWidthHelper.MaxWidth, DBGrid1.Canvas.TextWidth(Column.Field.DisplayText)) ;
```

It is not recognizing the Max function

Any help would be appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

The `Max` function is in the `Math` unit. Add this to your `Uses` clause.